# SwiftUI - Custom NavigationBar back button disables sliding gesture

Tags: swiftui

I made my own back button in SwiftUI without using the navigation bar. Everything works very well. But when I switch from the first view to the second view, I cannot slide back. I shared my codes with you, my avalanche for your solution suggestions.

First View:

```
struct LogInView: View {
  @State var showSignUpScreen = false
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
      NavigationLink(
        destination: SignUpView(),
        isActive: self.$showSignUpScreen,
        label: {
        Text("")
        })

      Button(action: {
        self.showSignUpScreen.toggle()
        }, label: {
        Text("Sign Up")
        .fontWeight(.semibold)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.3, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.06)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1.5))
            .padding(.bottom, 15)
      })

    }
    .navigationBarTitle("")
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
  }
}
```

Second View:

```
struct SignUpView: View {
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var present
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
      Button(action: {
        self.present.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }, label: {
        ZStack {
        Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
          .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))
          .foregroundColor(.blue)
          .padding(.leading, 10)
        }
      })
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("")
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `SignUpView`:

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clear
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .clear
}
```

And delete:

```
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

The idea:

`.navigationBarHidden(true)` seems to not only hide the bar but also disable sliding. So, in order to be able to slide, we can't do that. Fourtunately, we can also just hide it globally using `UINavigationBar.appearance()`, without the need of `.navigationBarHidden(true)`.

Note that if anywhere else inside your app you want the default `UINavigationBar` back, you would have to `init()` again and unhide it, since this sets the `appearance` globally.

I would recommend having a globally accessible function that contains the code to hide and unhide it if that's the case for you.